# How to crawl certain tags if there are other boxes which do not have the tags

Tags: python, web-crawler

Have no idea that How to collect values between certain tags when some boxes have that tags but others are not. (for example, text it have 'a' tag,  it doesn't)

I tried 'try-except' code and it worked.
But when I crawl some pages, it contains so many different tags so I have to use other code. it means, in case of shopping mall, some products have 'number of reviews' but some others are not. either 'delivery fee', 'discount rate' too.
So I tried count() but It doesn't word. I appreciate your help.

```
def get_info(item):
    info = item.find("div",{"class":"info"})
    price = info.find("span",{"class":"price"})
    num_review = info.find("a",{"class":"review"})
    delivery_fee = info.find("a",{"class":"fee"})

    if num_review.count() = 0 :
        result = {"price":price.text,
                  "review":"-",
                  "fee":delivery_fee.text}
        return result

    elif delivery_fee.count() = 0 :
        result = {"price":price.text,
                  "review":"-",
                  "fee":"-"}
        return result

    else :
        result = {"price":price.text,
                  "review":review.text,
                  "fee":delivery_fee.text}
        return result
```

Comment: Can you post your error traceback

Comment: In that case,
if num_reviews.count() = 0 :                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: if num_reviews.count() == 0 :                                   ^
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing equal operator

```
if len(num_review) == 0 :
  result = {"price":price.text,
                  "review":"-",
                  "fee":delivery_fee.text}
        return result
```

validate tag

```
if isinstance(num_review,Tag) and num_review in 'a':
    print("do something")
```

Add top of the script:

```
from bs4.element import Tag
```

EDIT:

```
def get_info(item):
    info = item.find("div",{"class":"info"})

    result = {'price':"",'review':"",'fee':""}
    for tag in info.findChildren():
        _class = tag.get('class')

        if _class in 'price':
          result['price'] = tag.text

        elif _class in 'review':
            result['review'] = tag.text

        elif _class in 'fee':
            result['fee'] = tag.text

    return result
```

Comment: Sorry,
if num_reviews.count() == 0 :

NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Because <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> object have no count() function

Comment: then do you have any idea that if there are more than 2 tags to examine(exist or not), how could I handle it?

Comment: @Jaguar Black can you give an example

Comment: New answer also give back 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: for example, in my question, in that web page(shopping mall) 'price' span tag exists in all item boxes, but 'review' and 'delivery fee' tags are not (exists in some box, but not in other boxes). I want to crawl all item boxes, if there are not tags, wanna get "-". If you give an e-mail address I could send you whole code (less than 50 lines)

Comment: @Jaguar Black I update my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. 'findchildren' is such a great function